# Apacite - Different citation output for multiple authors

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I have a question that I haven't been able to solve, even though I got through the documentation , web pages and `apacite.bst` code (although I'm quite new with this stuff). The problem is as follows:

Using `apacite` citation style package, I'd like

```
\citeA{ref} argued that the value of ...
```

to be rendered as

> *Borges and collaborators (2006) argued that the value of ...*

and at the same time, if the citation is not textual, the code

```
was proved \cite{ref}.
```

should be rendered as

> *was proved (Borges et al., 2006).*

In summary, when a citation results in an "et al.", I would like it to have different outputs whether it is a text citation (and colaborators) or a normal citation (et al.).

Already tested `renewcommand \BOthers` but it affects both types of citation.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the definition of `\BOthers`, we may test wether we're inside a `\citeA` citation command or not and typeset the appropriate string. Looking into `apacite.sty`, the internal `\@BAY` macro (the "after year" string) is a good test candidate -- its definition is `\BBCP` in "citeA" citations, and empty otherwise. For convenience, I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and its `\ifdefstring` macro to amend the definition of `\BOthers`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{%
    \ifdefstring{\@BAY}{\BBCP}{%
      and collaborators\hbox{}%
    }{%
      et al.\hbox{}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A. and B and C and D and E and F},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citeA{A01} argued~\dots

\dots\ was proved \cite{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you lockstep! It works perfect. Plus, I got the following (also working) solution from the apacite package `\let\oldcite\cite
\def\cite{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{et al.\hbox{}}
  \oldcite
}

\let\oldciteA\citeA
\def\citeA{%
  \renewcommand{\BOthers}[1]{and collaborators}
  \oldciteA
}` Anyway, excelent answer from you and got my problem solved!

Comment: @MiguelBorges Make sure if your solution also works with commands like `\fullciteauthor` used in the text body.

Comment: Since it only redefines those two commands, I suspect it won't work with `\fullciteauthor`... Your solution seems more comprehensive then. Again, thanks.